# getExternalFilesDir() problems

Tags: android

So the app I'm working on is making use of the external files dir to store some downloaded information. The issue I'm running into is, very ocassionally the getExternalFilesDir() method will return null. My understanding of this method might be flawed, but I was under the impression that it would return null under **TWO** distinct scenarios:

1) The user has an SD card slot but does NOT have an sd card mounted (or the SD card is mounted but plugged into a computer as mass storage option)

2) The app does not actually have read/write permissions

The app has the read/write permissions (it must since it works in most scenarios), and I I'm checking for the first case with the following code:

```
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()))
            {
                editor.putBoolean(AUDIO_LOCATION_KEY, true);
                subPath = context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath();
            }
```

The app is crashing with a null pointer exception from the getExternalFilesDir line. I can't reproduce the crash,  Is there something I'm missing? I would've that that if that check passed that we'd be guaranteed to get something back. Any insight would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any commonalities in the devices experiencing this problem? What is the specific `Context` you are using? Is there anything possibly sketchy about the timing of when you are doing this work (e.g., `context` is an `Activity`, and you're calling this code before `onCreate()`)?

Comment: There does not seem to be any commonality - all different makes of phones. The context I'm using is the starting activity of the app. I'm passing that as self to the class constructor

     AudioCueDownloadManager audioCueDlManager = AudioCueDownloadManager.getInstance(this);

where "this" is the starting activity of the app. This is getting called in that activities onCreate method.

Comment: "This is getting called in that activities onCreate method" -- after `super.onCreate()`?

Comment: Yep after super.oncreate()